# Multidimensional array in PHP using foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is an array from which I need to sort out the dept name, the full name and the salary , whose salary are above 10000rs. 
The array is:

```
Array
 (
 [PHP] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Jay
                [salary] => 8000
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => Raj
                [salary] => 15000
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => Mihir
                [salary] => 12000
            )

    )

[Flex] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Vijay
                [salary] => 14000
            )

    )

[System] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => Kishan
                [salary] => 5000
            )

    )

 )
```

I am totally confused inside the loops of foreach and don't know how to call each value from the array.

My code allows me to display only names.

Can i know what is the best way to print and work with multidimensional arrays in PHP.

My code:

```
  foreach($newArray as $x=>$x_value){

                        foreach ($x_value as $y=> $y_value){
                                 if($y_value['salary']>10000)                                    
                                echo $y_value['name']." has ". $y_value['salary']. ", ";


                            }
                    }
```

Comment: In this case if you don't need the information of the shallow end of the array, you might wanna flatten the array and work with that.

Comment: exactly what do you want to do with this array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following, Tested and working

```
$filterArray = array();
$i           = 0;
foreach($salary as $dept => $employee){
    foreach($employee as $index => $data){
        if($data['salary'] > 10000){
            $filterArray[$i]['deprtment'] = $dept;
            $filterArray[$i]['name']      = $data['name'];
            $filterArray[$i]['salary']    = $data['salary'];
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Result :-

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [deprtment] => PHP
        [name] => Raj
        [salary] => 15000
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [deprtment] => PHP
        [name] => Mihir
        [salary] => 12000
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [deprtment] => Flex
        [name] => Vijay
        [salary] => 14000
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution for looping over the arrays.

```
foreach ($bigArray as $department => $employees) {
    foreach ($employees as $employee) {
        if ($employee["salary"] > 10000) {
            echo "Department: " . $department;
            echo "Employee: " . $employee;
            echo "Salary: " . $salary;
        } else {
            echo $person . " has no money.";
        }
    }
}
```

This will output what you were trying to print in your example.

Output for the first employee:

```
Department: <department name>
Employee: Raj
Salary: 15000
```

In the future, you should include the department names in your example array since your example doesn't have all of the information you are trying to print; we can't print something that doesn't exist.

Comment: how will u print dep like PHP or FLEX as per the given array in question.

Comment: You're right. I believe I missed that part of the question's requirements.

Comment: i have answered it below ,u can refer that

Answer (score 1):

Your input is nested array. So you have to use foreach +for loop:

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($newArray as $x=>$x_value)
{
     foreach ($i=0;$i<count($x_value);$i++)
     {
        if($x_value[$i]['salary']>10000)                                  
        {
           if(isset($final_array[$x]))
           {
              array_push($final_array[$x],array("name"=>$x_value[$i]['name'],"salary"=>$x_value[$i]['salary']));
           }
           else
           {
              $final_array[$x] = array();
              array_push($final_array[$x],array("name"=>$x_value[$i]['name'],"salary"=>$x_value[$i]['salary']));
           }
        }
     }
}
```

$final_array print dep wise name & salary which is max than 10000
Output :

```
Array
(
[PHP] => Array
    (
     [0]=> Array
        (
          [name] => Raj
          [salary] => 15000
        )
     [1]=> Array
        (
          [name] => Mihir
          [salary] => 12000
        )
    )

[Flex] => Array
      (
       [0]=> Array
          (
            [name] => Vijay
            [salary] => 14000)
          )
      )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if i've got you correctly, but if you need to filter out all the people from the sub-arrays (PHP, Flex, System, ...) and then sort them either by their name or salary, you could do it in  this or a similar way:

```
$array = [
    'PHP' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Jay',
            'salary' => 8000
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Raj',
            'salary' => 15000
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Mihir',
            'salary' => 12000
        ]
    ],
    'Flex' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Vijay',
            'salary' => 14000
        ]
    ],
    'System' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Kishan',
            'salary' => 5000
        ]
    ]
];

$array_people = [];
$array_sorted = [];
$sort_by = 'name'; // Array key name
$sort_desc = false;
$min_salary = 10000;

foreach ($array as $type => $people)
{
    foreach ($people as $info)
    {
        if ($info['salary'] >= $min_salary) {
            $array_sorted[] = $info[$sort_by];
            $array_people[] = $info;
        }
    }
}

if ($sort_desc) {
    // Sort descending
    arsort($array_sorted);
} else {
    // Sort ascending
    asort($array_sorted);
}

$array_final = [];

foreach (array_keys($array_sorted) as $index)
{
    $array_final[] = $array_people[$index];
}

print_r($array_final);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Mihir
            [salary] => 12000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Raj
            [salary] => 15000
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Vijay
            [salary] => 14000
        )

)
```

The first thing you need to do, is to process the main array in a way, that allows you to keep just the items you want - this items need to be stored in a different (empty) array (in this case `$array_people`).

While detecting the items you need, you've to get out all the values you want to sort by - this can be done at the same time. It's just about creating a new array which will contain just the values you will sort by (in this case `$array_sorted`).

Then comes the easier part. The next thing to do is sorting the array. There exist a [bunch of functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php), that can help you with this.

The functions i've used (`asort` and `arsort`) are keeping the original key of the item, so you can sort the array containing all the people by the **keys** of the sorted array (see the code up above).

And that's all, now you have an array with filtered and sorted people :) ... hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after reading so many solutions I personally believe that some of them are totally confusing for a newbie so here is the solution I actually implemented which is totally simple and easy to understand the flow of multi-dimensional array.

```
  foreach($newArray as $x=>$x_value){

                        foreach ($x_value as $y=> $y_value){
                                 if($y_value['salary']>10000){     

                                echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<td>"; echo $y_value['name'];  echo "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>"; echo $x;  echo "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>"; echo $y_value['salary'];  echo "</td>";

                                echo "</tr>";


                                 }

                    }

                 }
```

The output will be like, (if u use table )

[image]